# do loop within a macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

The code below is returning the following error message:

`Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, INPUT, PUT.`

```
%macro run_calculation(amt, t, r);
    data customer_value;
    i=&r./100.; 
    do n=0 to t;
    S=&amt.*[(1+ calculated i)^t - 1]/calculated i
    end;
    run;
%mend;


%run_calculation(amt=1000, t=8, r=5);
```

Expected output is S value at each t in a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few comments:

- You are missing a semi-colon `;` when assigning S.
- You don't have to use `calculated i`, use `i` directly.
- Power operator in SAS is `**` and not `^`.
- You point to `t` instead of the macro-variable `&t.` in the do loop statement.
- You increment `n`, not `t` so you need to use `n` in your formula.
- Use parenthesis, not brackets.
- You are missing an explicit output statement in order to get S value for each n.

```
%macro run_calculation(amt, t, r);
    data customer_value;
        i=&r./100.;
        do n=0 to &t.;
            S=&amt.*((1+i)**n - 1)/i;
            output;
        end;
    run;
%mend;

%run_calculation(amt=1000, t=8, r=5);
```

```
  i   n    S
 0.05 0 0
 0.05 1 1000
 0.05 2 2050
 0.05 3 3152.5
 0.05 4 4310.125
 0.05 5 5525.63125
 0.05 6 6801.9128125
 0.05 7 8142.0084531
 0.05 8 9549.1088758
```